# How do you change the git commit email on a commit without an email?

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project with a group of people and had just got a new computer. After completing this project, I realized that I had forgotten to set up my email address locally so my commits would be marked as my email address. Instead, all of my commits are just under my name and my contributions aren't showing up in the repository or on my profile page. Is there a way to fix this manually?

I've tried using git rebase interactive and going through my commits individually, but each time I change the author and move on, I get a merge conflict for some reason. I'm not sure if resolving this conflict will change the final state of the repository, so I'm not sure how to handle it. I've also tried using a git filter-branch, but I'm not sure how it works so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = COMMITED_NAME; then
  GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL= MY_EMAIL
fi'
```

Running that gave me this error: 
`line 406: test: too many arguments`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: quote the committed name

Comment: `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=MY_EMAIL` <- no spaces around `=`!

Comment: Ok I tried these fixes and now it's changing all the commits to be authored by me regardless of who the author is. Any idea of why it's not checking to see if it has the my author name first?

Comment: Because perhaps `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` is set in your current environment and you forgot to re-export it in the `git filter-branch --env-filter`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch/2.12.3#_examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all the fixes discussed in the comments the code should look like this:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "COMMITED_NAME"; then
  GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=MY_EMAIL
  export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
fi'
```